# Deleting a List of Labels From The Tkinter Window Placed In The Grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

a. Have a scenario where I had created a list of labels as shown below.

```
class test_template:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master

...

def nb_code(self):
    if nb_cnt == 0:
        for i in range (int(no_of_fs)):
            self.enul = Label(root, text="Enter The Number Of Fruits In Basket%d\n"%i)
            self.enul.grid(row=i+1)

    # Trying To Delete The List Of Labels  
    elif nb_cnt == 2:
        for i in range (int(no_of_fs)):
            self.enul.grid_forget()
```

b. Say if I have a list of 3 Labels, when I try to delete them by putting in a loop, only they first one gets deleted which makes sense because that was holding the Label information for the last Label assigned.

c. **But then in this scenario what I need to do to delete the complete list of Labels ? Can be it be done by searching for the "Label" name in the total grid and delete them ? or how can it be done ?**

Please share in your comments !!

Comment: Can you keep a list of Labels rather than reassigning to the same variable?

Comment: @FamousJameous: Nice Idea... I tried appending the Labels into a list of labels and deleting them based on the list number and it worked fine.. But Was looking for any other idea apart from the same, if the list of labels are assigned to the same variable ?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that. Is there a reason for avoiding a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `root` children and search for your labels.

```
for child in root.children.values():
    info = child.grid_info()
    if info['column'] == 0:
        child.grid_forget()
```